# Splitting multi-line cells into rows

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I'd like to be able to split multi-lined cells into rows using only 1 command.

I have tried using the command

```
=transpose(split(A2," "))
```

but when trying to add the 'tab' key as a custom separator it doesn't seem to allow me.

I've tried entering the words 'tab' 'shift' and 'enter' into this custom separator field but none seem to perform the desired function.

[image: CUSTOM Separator]

[image: **Ideal beginning and end product**]

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the ASCII codes for Tab (#9) and the CHAR function, so that your formula would look like this:

```
=transpose(split(A2,CHAR(9)))
```